# what is the equivalent function of res.json() in python

Tags: python, equivalent

"I have to implement a web hook for api.ai which takes json as output from the web hook". How to give asynchronous output in python equivalent in node [res.json(...)]. I need to know res.json() equivalent in python.

Comment: I don't totally get what you're asking for but I bet Python's built-in `json` module will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just json which ships with Python. It serializes data to a string. That string can then be read back in. Most languages support json.

```
import json

data = [1, 2]
str_data = json.dumps(data)  # "[1, 2]"
value = json.loads(str_data)
print(value == data)
```